# Subscript out of range during copying an excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

i have been trying to copy values from one excel sheet to another using the following macro

```
Sub Sample()
  Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet

  Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")
  Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet11")

  wsI.Range(wsI.Range("A1").Value).Copy wsO.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

But unfortunately it is showing Runtime error '9':
Subscript out of range

where am i going wrong please help !!

Comment: Good practices (not necessarily BEST PRACTICES) suggest to explicitly calculate indices before using them. As such, create a variable to serve as the parameter for the `wsI.Range` function and evaluate it (debug mode) before actual use. This will show you were the issue is.

Comment: it is showing error at this point Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")

Comment: It means that it does not know what `Sheet5` is. Try providing your own name to each sheet. It helps in debugging (and makes no difference in execution).

Comment: @leo were you able to pass the `Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")` line ? do you have "Sheet5" in this workbbok ? is this code working for you now ?

Comment: yes after renaming i am able to pass it . But there is some problem regarding copying cells whiching are fetching its value from other excel file

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the below line to

```
wsI.Range(wsI.Range("A1").Value).Copy wsO.Range("A1")
```

to

```
wsI.Range("A1").Copy wsO.Range("A1")
```